# adding a rewrite rule in wordpress functions file

Tags: htaccess

I have a section of my functions.php file (which is definitely running as I ran a die() and it showed.)

It is as follows:

```
function looky_setPermalink() {
    add_rewrite_rule(  
         "looky/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?",  
         "index.php?page_id=4006&page_id=4006&a=view&cat=$matches[1]&where=$matches[2]",  
        "top"
    );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'looky_setPermalink' );
```

And it doesn't seem to work when I go to looky/category/location, I just get told that it can not be found.
Is there anything you can see that I might be doing wrong?

Regards

Matt

Comment: You flushed the rewrite rules, right...?

Comment: @tf I tried adding 'flush_rewrite_rules();' above my add_rewrite_rule and that didn't seem to make a difference (I hope I answered your question correctly)

Comment: Sorry, I mean below, not above.

Comment: your rule (sort of) works when I try it. you need to single-quote the query string argument rather than double-quote, so PHP doesn't try to expand the `$matches` vars, but it should still load the page with ID 4006 (which you've got in there twice by the way). make sure first that pretty permalinks in general are working, then verify it's not a plugin or theme conflict by disabling plugins and using a default theme. a quick way to flush your permalinks for testing is to visit the permalinks settings page in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the query vars via the `query_vars`-hook in addition to the defintion of the rewrite rule in the `init`-hook?

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_add_query_var_function' );
function my_add_query_var_function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'a';
    $vars[] = 'cat';
    $vars[] = 'where';
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: This wasn't really my question but I understand why you thought it might be.